# What kind of caching machanism is used over at Wikipedia?

Tags: php, caching, memcached, wikipedia

If you open up your mozilla Firefox web browser and turn on firebug to check for incoming and outcoming network traffic, you see that, when you look at **Wikipedia articles**, the amount of **cached content** is very large.

Unless the article in question has many pictures, most of the content comes from the cache.

**I'd like to know whether that is done by the browser itself or if it's some underlying PHP Caching mechanism. (is that what they call memcache?APC?)** It works very well so I'd like to know how they do it.

Comment: What you see in Firebug isn't server-side cacheing (memcache, APC, ...), but client side caching of images, scripts or stylesheet files (via the Expires header)

Comment: “[…] most of the content comes from the cache.” – How did you determine that? What cache do you mean?

Comment: @nikic I see. Do browsers do the same thing with flash-based content? Do different browsers do it differently or is it default? Post an answer so I can "green tick" you.

Comment: @Gumbo Yeah. That's what I'd like to know. Firebug tells me the amount of "cached content". It does not say anything else.

Comment: @Felipe Almeida: In that case it’s probably the browsers local cache.

Comment: @Tomalak you edited "Thanks in advance" out? Is that against SO guidelines?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida It's not a hard and fast rule, but _usually_ the hi/thanks bit is removed to keep the question clean and clutter free.

Comment: @Felipe: What JohnP said. I know that you were just being polite, but since SO is not a message board, greetings, thanks and signatures are redundant. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memcacahe, APC etc are server side data stores. You basically use it as a key value store so you don't have to ping your database all the time.

However, what you're actually seeing is a site being loaded on a primed cache. This is the technique of telling your web server to let the browser know that your commonly used resources haven't changed since the last time you viewed it. This effect is achieved by setting [far future headers](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires) so that the browser doesn't keep requesting the resources. A lot of sites use this technique, including SO.

Here's a great source to read up on, if you want more info : http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: Hmmm.. Makes sense. That's a very good link, by the way. Thanks.